# RecyclerView with Multiple View Type with continued position counting

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-view

Is there a way to use mutiple `View` types in a `RecyclerView` without any items getting replaced?

For `position` 0 and every 4th `position` in my `RecyclerView`, I want the 2nd `View` type to be shown without replacing what would've been in that position if the 1st `View` type was there. I.e. show the 2nd `View` type then the intended 1st `View` type afterwards.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(holder) {
        is ViewHolderA -> {
            MobileAds.initialize(mCtx) {}
            mAdView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView)
            val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
        }

        is ViewHolderB -> {
        val product = my[holder.adapterPosition]

        holder.tvTitle.text = product.itemTitle
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (position % 4 == 0) {
        typeA
    } else {
        typeB
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add empty item in every position%4 == 0 position.

Comment: I think you need to write.

Comment: Inside your `onBindViewHolder` bind items from `position - position / 4 - 1`.

Comment: @Pawel I've added the `onBindViewHolder` method to my question. Which part of the method does that need to go?

Comment: @MacaronLover I don't see it

Comment: @Pawel It should be there. Try reloading the page

Answer (score 1):

Modify you `onBindViewHolder` to bind items from `position - position / 4 - 1` instead.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(holder) {
        is ViewHolderA -> {
            MobileAds.initialize(mCtx) {}
            mAdView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView)
            val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
        }

        is ViewHolderB -> {
            val positionToBind = position - position / 4 - 1
            val product = my[positionToBind]
            holder.tvTitle.text = product.itemTitle
        }
    }
}
```

This will return

```
position 0: -1 (ad so it doesnt apply)
position 1: 0 (item A)
position 2: 1 (item B)
position 3: 2 (item C)
position 4: 2 (ad so it doesnt apply)
position 5: 3 (item D)
etc.
```

Comment: Great. How can position 0 be changed to a `TextView` type instead of an `Ad` type?

Comment: if you want item A at position 0 then don't subtract 1 from calculation, if you want another viewtype just add another case to your `getItemViewType()`

Comment: That didn't work for me unfortunately. I used `position - position / 4` but now the list begins with 'Item B'. Does `return if (position % 4 == 0)` { need to change?

Comment: yes obviously since you still return an ad viewtype for position 0

Comment: In this scenario, do you know what the `0` means & what I would need to change `position % 4 == 0` to?